# Access function in Component.js from Controller in ui5

Tags: sapui5

I have a function inside my Component.js. I want to access this function from my controller. Please provide suggestions on how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, to access getContentDensityClass() in your Component.js, try

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getContentDensityClass()
```